# Can't access element in an array that is created by the ouput of ls in shell script

Tags: shell, unix

I have a list of things that I want to store into an array. The list is an output from a series of split-awk operations:

```
Array=$(ls -ld  /sys/block/sd*/device | awk -F'/' '{print $1}')
```

The command

```
$ ls -ld  /sys/block/sd*/device | awk -F'/' '{print $1}'
```

would return (for example)

```
0
1
```

If I want to store the results into an array such that each number is an element, I should access it by

```
echo ${Array[0]}
echo ${Array[1]}
```

However, the second command return nothing while the first one return

```
0 1
```

I originally expected the result to be that

```
Array[0] = 0
Array[1] = 1
```

Where did I do wrong? Thanks.

Comment: That's not an array assignment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are storing the result in a single variable, not in an *array*. Change it to to use *compound assignment*:

```
Array=($(ls -ld  /sys/block/sd*/device | awk -F'/' '{print $1}'))
```

(Notice the *extra* brackets around).

Answer (score 0):

```
$ arr=(
    $(
        printf '%s\n' /sys/block/sd*/device |
            xargs readlink -f |
            grep -oP '\d+(?=:\d+:\d:\d+)'
    )
)
$ echo ${arr[0]}
0
```